# Django - File name '' includes path elements exception, isn't the name supposed to include the path relative to MEDIA_ROOT?

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I am working through a Django/Vue [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg5zkd9nm6w&list=WL&index=32).  I have a url setup 'latest-products' that should show the serialized Products but I am getting an exception when the thumbnail doesn't exist and is created with the make_thumbnail function in the Product class of models.py.

This is the exception:

Exception Type: SuspiciousFileOperation at /api/v1/latest-products/
Exception Value: File name 'uploads/winter3.jpg' includes path elements

This is the result I am expecting:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rOrY.png)

From the Django File [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/) , the name is supposed to be "The name of the file including the relative path from MEDIA_ROOT."

So, my question is why am I getting a SuspiciousFileOperation exception?

```
#models.py

from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

from django.core.files import File
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.slug}/'

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_added',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.category.slug}/{self.slug}/'

    def get_image(self):
        if self.image:
            return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + self.image.url
        return ''

    def get_thumbnail(self):
        if self.thumbnail:
            return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + self.thumbnail.url
        else:
            if self.image:
                self.thumbnail = self.make_thumbnail(self.image)
                self.save() # <------------------------------------------- exception occurs here

                return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + self.thumbnail.url
            else:
                return ''
    
    def make_thumbnail(self, image, size=(300, 200)):
        img = Image.open(image)
        img.convert('RGB')
        img.thumbnail(size)

        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        img.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality=85)

        thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)

        return thumbnail
```

```
#serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Category, Product

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "get_absolute_url",
            "description",
            "price",
            "get_image",
            "get_thumbnail"
        )
```

```
#urls.py

from django.urls import path, include

from product import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('latest-products/', views.LatestProductsList.as_view()),
]
```

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Product
from .serializers import ProductSerializer

class LatestProductsList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        products = Product.objects.all()[0:4]
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/latest-products/

Django Version: 3.2.2
Python Version: 3.9.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'corsheaders',
 'djoser',
 'product']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\djackets_django\product\views.py", line 13, in get
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 745, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 502, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 457, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 102, in get_attribute
    instance = instance()
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\djackets_django\product\models.py", line 50, in get_thumbnail
    self.save()
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    values = [(f, None, (getattr(self, f.attname) if raw else f.pre_save(self, False)))
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 842, in <listcomp>
    values = [(f, None, (getattr(self, f.attname) if raw else f.pre_save(self, False)))
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 302, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 88, in save
    name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 316, in generate_filename
    filename = validate_file_name(filename)
  File "C:\Code\Djackets\environment_3_9_4\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\utils.py", line 8, in validate_file_name
    raise SuspiciousFileOperation("File name '%s' includes path elements" % name)

Exception Type: SuspiciousFileOperation at /api/v1/latest-products/
Exception Value: File name 'uploads/winter3.jpg' includes path elements
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem yesterday just like you and I found a solution just a minute ago.

The problem was caused by the file name just as the Django debug mode tried to tell you, "File name 'uploads/winter3.jpg' includes path elements".

"uploads/winter3.jpg" is not a legal path name, so what we need to do is to remove "uploads/" from the name of the image, make the name to be "winter3.jpe" and that is really simple.

Here is the code of the solution for this problem

```
def make_thumbnail(self, image, size=(300, 200)):
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.convert('RGB')
    img.thumbnail(size)

    thumb_io = BytesIO()
    img.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', qulity=85)

    # just add replace("uploads/","") after the image.name
    thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name.replace("uploads/",""))
    return thumbnail
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  I actually did something similar to work around this, which is thumbnail_name = f'{Path(image.name).stem}_thumbnail.jpg'. The thumbnail then gets saved with the same name as the image plus "_thumbnail".  Notice though that in the screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rOrY.png) that the thumbnail is in  uploads/uploads/winter3.jpg, so it does seem like it was saved with the name uploads/winter3.jpg in the uploads folder.  Also the Django documentation on Django.core.files.File says it is "the name of the file including the relative path from MEDIA_ROOT."